# Dynasty Warriors 8 Xtreme Legends said VCOMP100.DLL is missing?

Tags: dynasty-warriors-8

[image: Dynasty Warriors 8 Xtreme Legends-VComp100DLL]

When I open the game Dynasty Warriors 8 Xtreme Legends, it just keeps saying VCOMP100.DLL is missing.

[Some people](https://steamcommunity.com/app/278080/discussions/0/135508833659908180/) recommend installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010, but I check & see that I've already install MS Visual C++ 2010.

[image: vcredist2010]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I get a downvote, Is it because it's not appropriate to ask a "fix bug" question on this site? All I want is just to share my experience to help people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed MS Visual C++ 2010, but still doesn't work, then try this:

Step 1: Download vcomp100.dll - **32 bit version** - at https://www.dll-files.com/vcomp100.dll.html , must be 32 bit version because the game is 32 bit.
[image]

Step 2: Now you should have the file: vcomp100.zip, extract this file and copy the file vcomp100.dll into the Dynasty Warriors 8 Xtreme Legends' install folder.
[image: Fix VComp100.dll For Dynasty Warrior 8]